# Echarts Datazoom in several graphs

Tags: javascript

I want to make Datazoom for all graphs, but it just works on the first graph.
I tried to make several Datazoom like this

```
 DataZoom: [
              {
                  type: 'inside'
              },
               {
                   type: 'inside'
               },
                {
                    type: 'inside'
                },
                 {
                     type: 'inside'
                 }
            ]
```

But it doesn't work.

Also, Should I add more details in there?

[image]

```js
 var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
        var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
        var option;
        
        const data = [["2000-06-05", 116], ["2000-06-06", 129], ["2000-06-07", 135], ["2000-06-08", 86], ["2000-06-09", 73], ["2000-06-10", 85], ["2000-06-11", 73], ["2000-06-12", 68], ["2000-06-13", 92], ["2000-06-14", 130], ["2000-06-15", 245], ["2000-06-16", 139], ["2000-06-17", 115], ["2000-06-18", 111], ["2000-06-19", 309], ["2000-06-20", 206], ["2000-06-21", 137], ["2000-06-22", 128], ["2000-06-23", 85], ["2000-06-24", 94], ["2000-06-25", 71], ["2000-06-26", 106], ["2000-06-27", 84], ["2000-06-28", 93], ["2000-06-29", 85], ["2000-06-30", 73], ["2000-07-01", 83], ["2000-07-02", 125], ["2000-07-03", 107], ["2000-07-04", 82], ["2000-07-05", 44], ["2000-07-06", 72], ["2000-07-07", 106], ["2000-07-08", 107], ["2000-07-09", 66], ["2000-07-10", 91], ["2000-07-11", 92], ["2000-07-12", 113], ["2000-07-13", 107], ["2000-07-14", 131], ["2000-07-15", 111], ["2000-07-16", 64], ["2000-07-17", 69], ["2000-07-18", 88], ["2000-07-19", 77], ["2000-07-20", 83], ["2000-07-21", 111], ["2000-07-22", 57], ["2000-07-23", 55], ["2000-07-24", 60]];
        const dateList = data.map(function (item) {
            return item[0];
        });
        const valueList = data.map(function (item) {
            return item[1];
        });
        option = {
            // Make gradient line here
            visualMap: [
              {
              }
            ],
            title: [
              {
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph1'
              },
              {
                  top: '25%',
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph2'
              },
              {
                  top: '50%',
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph3'
              },
              {
                  top: '75%',
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph4'
              },
            ],
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer: {
                    type: 'cross'
                }
            },
            toolbox: {
                right: 10,
                feature: {
                    dataZoom: {
                        yAxisIndex: 'none'
                    },
                    restore: {},
                    saveAsImage: {}
                }
            },
            grid: [
            {
                top: '5%',
                bottom: '80%'
            },
            {
                top: '30%',
                bottom: '55%'
            },
            {
                top: '55%',
                bottom: '30%'
            },
            {
                top: '80%',
            }
            ],
            xAxis: [
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 0
              },
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 1
              },
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 2
              },
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 3
              }
            ],
            yAxis: [
              { gridIndex: 0 },
              { gridIndex: 1 },
              { gridIndex: 2 },
              { gridIndex: 3 }
            ],
            dataZoom: [
              {
                  type: 'inside'
              }
            ],
            series: [
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList
              },
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList,
                  xAxisIndex: 1,
                  yAxisIndex: 1
              },
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList,
                  xAxisIndex: 2,
                  yAxisIndex: 2
              },
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList,
                  xAxisIndex: 3,
                  yAxisIndex: 3
              }
            ]
        };

        myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="min-height:1000px; width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work" ? Can you [edit] your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure [dataZoom-inside.xAxisIndex](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-inside.xAxisIndex). Here a worked version of your example :

```js
 var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
        var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
        var option;
        
        const data = [["2000-06-05", 116], ["2000-06-06", 129], ["2000-06-07", 135], ["2000-06-08", 86], ["2000-06-09", 73], ["2000-06-10", 85], ["2000-06-11", 73], ["2000-06-12", 68], ["2000-06-13", 92], ["2000-06-14", 130], ["2000-06-15", 245], ["2000-06-16", 139], ["2000-06-17", 115], ["2000-06-18", 111], ["2000-06-19", 309], ["2000-06-20", 206], ["2000-06-21", 137], ["2000-06-22", 128], ["2000-06-23", 85], ["2000-06-24", 94], ["2000-06-25", 71], ["2000-06-26", 106], ["2000-06-27", 84], ["2000-06-28", 93], ["2000-06-29", 85], ["2000-06-30", 73], ["2000-07-01", 83], ["2000-07-02", 125], ["2000-07-03", 107], ["2000-07-04", 82], ["2000-07-05", 44], ["2000-07-06", 72], ["2000-07-07", 106], ["2000-07-08", 107], ["2000-07-09", 66], ["2000-07-10", 91], ["2000-07-11", 92], ["2000-07-12", 113], ["2000-07-13", 107], ["2000-07-14", 131], ["2000-07-15", 111], ["2000-07-16", 64], ["2000-07-17", 69], ["2000-07-18", 88], ["2000-07-19", 77], ["2000-07-20", 83], ["2000-07-21", 111], ["2000-07-22", 57], ["2000-07-23", 55], ["2000-07-24", 60]];
        const dateList = data.map(function (item) {
            return item[0];
        });
        const valueList = data.map(function (item) {
            return item[1];
        });
        option = {
            // Make gradient line here
            visualMap: [
              {
              }
            ],
            title: [
              {
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph1'
              },
              {
                  top: '25%',
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph2'
              },
              {
                  top: '50%',
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph3'
              },
              {
                  top: '75%',
                  left: 'center',
                  text: 'Graph4'
              },
            ],
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'axis',
                axisPointer: {
                    type: 'cross'
                }
            },
            toolbox: {
                right: 10,
                feature: {
                    dataZoom: {
                        yAxisIndex: 'none'
                    },
                    restore: {},
                    saveAsImage: {}
                }
            },
            grid: [
            {
                top: '5%',
                bottom: '80%'
            },
            {
                top: '30%',
                bottom: '55%'
            },
            {
                top: '55%',
                bottom: '30%'
            },
            {
                top: '80%',
            }
            ],
            xAxis: [
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 0
              },
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 1
              },
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 2
              },
              {
                  data: dateList,
                  gridIndex: 3
              }
            ],
            yAxis: [
              { gridIndex: 0 },
              { gridIndex: 1 },
              { gridIndex: 2 },
              { gridIndex: 3 }
            ],
            dataZoom: [
              {
                  type: 'inside', 
                  xAxisIndex: [0, 1, 2, 3],
              }
            ],
            series: [
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList
              },
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList,
                  xAxisIndex: 1,
                  yAxisIndex: 1
              },
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList,
                  xAxisIndex: 2,
                  yAxisIndex: 2
              },
              {
                  type: 'line',
                  showSymbol: false,
                  data: valueList,
                  xAxisIndex: 3,
                  yAxisIndex: 3
              }
            ]
        };

        myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="min-height:1000px; width:100%;"></div>
```